# Using blessed CodeRefs with Moose type constraints

Tags: perl, moose, moosex-types

We use Moose classes that serialize iterators into various output formats.  We describe the iterator as an attribute:

```
has iterator => (
    is => 'ro',
    isa => 'CodeRef',
    required => 1,
);
```

This has worked fine so far, but we have lately been using [Iterator::Simple](https://metacpan.org/module/Iterator%3a%3aSimple) to prepare iterators for later consumption.  This means that we can go about writing this:

```
has iterator => (
    is => 'ro',
    isa => 'CodeRef|Iterator::Simple::Iterator',
    required => 1,
);
```

And allow our serializers to accept the iterator class correctly.  However, that seems to be a incomplete solution.

Is there a way in Moose to specify the constraint that the attribute must be callable?  I suspect it may be possible with [Moose::Util::TypeConstraints](http://search.cpan.org/~doy/Moose-2.0401/lib/Moose/Util/TypeConstraints.pm) and using [overload::Overloaded](https://metacpan.org/module/overload)  on `&{}` to check, but I'd like to know if anyone has created a module to do this already or if there is a Moose-standard way to test for this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`CodeRef` only allows unblessed code references. Fortunately, it's easy to make your own types.

Define `Callable` as shown below, then use it instead of `CodeRef`. It allows the following:

- Unblessed code references.
- Blessed code references.
- Objects that pretend to be code references (i.e. those that overload `&{}`).

```
use Moose::Util::TypeConstraints;
use overload     qw( );
use Scalar::Util qw( );

subtype 'Callable'
    => as 'Ref'
    => where {
          Scalar::Util::reftype($_) eq 'CODE'
             ||
          Scalar::Util::blessed($_) && overload::Method($_, "&{}")
       }

    # Written such that parent's inline_as needs not be prepended.
    => inline_as {'(
          (Scalar::Util::reftype('.$_[1].') // "") eq 'CODE'
             ||
          Scalar::Util::blessed('.$_[1].') && overload::Method('.$_[1].', "&{}")
       )'};

no Moose::Util::TypeConstraints;
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you know enough to get from [Scalar::Util::reftype](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Scalar%3a%3aUtil#reftype)?